# python for getting big number string form a column

Tags: python

My data will look like

```
N4
AP11
AP7
AP7
N3
AP12
AP8
N3
AP13
AP9

N3
AP14
AP10
AP10
N0
AP15
AP11
```

I want to print maximum of string. Output would be like this:If in the data N has N4 as highest it should print N4 and from the AP strings it should print AP15 as highest.

Comment: is the data saved in a file, in a list or ...?

Comment: does it have only `N` and `AP` strings?

Comment: saved in file and extracted to dict[] in script.

Comment: Please show us your existing code so that we can help you fix it.

Comment: one more is there 'PP'

Comment: I haven't tried to get this output, i just blocked to do.

Comment: Really, you guys spoon feeding here. Op dosen't have shown effort or try.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
s = "N4 AP11 AP7 AP7 N3 AP12 AP8 N3 AP13 AP9 N3 AP14 AP10 AP10 N0 AP15 AP11"

def get_max_by_start(start, string):
    values = re.findall(r"\b{0}\d+\b".format(start), string)
    return max(values, key=lambda x: int(x.replace(start, '')))

print get_max_by_start('N', s)
print get_max_by_start('AP', s)
```

Output:

```
>>> N4
>>> AP15
```

Comment: FWIW, `max` can be given a `key` argument, so your `return` statement can be simplified to `return max(values, key=lambda x: int(x.replace(start, '')))`

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx:

```
import re
lst = ['N4', 'AP11', 'AP7', 'AP7', 'N3', 'AP12', 'AP8','N3','AP13','AP9']
pattern = re.compile('([\d]+)')

max_ = 0
max_el = 0

for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    current = int(re.findall(pattern, item)[0])
    if current > max_:
        max_ = current
        max_el = i

print("Maximum value: %s" % lst[max_el])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could simply use the `max()` function. Use `.readlines()` to fetch a list (in the example below it is `lst`) containing the lines and try the following:

```
>>> max(int(i.replace("AP", "")) for i in lst if i.startswith("AP"))
15
```

Create function which you can then reuse.

```
def max_from_list(start_str, lst):
    max_no = max(int(i.replace(start_str, "")) for i in lst if i.startswith(start_str))
    return start_str + str(max_no)


>>> max_from_list("AP", given_list)
'AP15'
>>> max_from_list("AP", given_list)
'N4'
```

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes the data is a single string with the items separated by whitespace. It uses a regex to find each item and split it into an upper-case alphabetic key and a numeric value. It then stores the numeric values as integers in a dictionary of lists. Then the `max` function can easily find the maximum integer associated with a given key.

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

data = 'N4 AP11 AP7 AP7 N3 AP12 AP8 N3 AP13 AP9 N3 AP14 AP10 AP10 N0 AP15 AP11'

pat = re.compile(r'([A-Z]+)(\d+)')

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in pat.findall(data):
    d[k].append(int(v))

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k + str(max(v)))
```

**output**

```
AP15
N4
```